# TSQL Query - how to get WHERE conditions to "add up"?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**EDIT3:**

I have the following table:

| item | In-House Manufacturing | Purchasing | Outsourcing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| B | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| C | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| D | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| E | 0 | 1 | 1 |

The user wants to filter that data by property. Filtering for "In-House Manufacturing"= 1 should show items with "In-House Manufacturing" = 1 only. Adding a filter for "purchasing"= 1 to the first filter should show all items that can either be manufactured in-house or be purchased. Adding another filter for "outsourcing" should also show items that are outsourced.

But setting any of the filters to 0 means, that I don't want to see results where that property is true.

Not setting a filter for an property means: I dont' care which value that property has.

**EDIT2:**
More clarification

- Var1= NULL, Var 2 = NULL, Var3 = NULL
  All results are allowed
- Var1= 1, Var 2 = NULL, Var3 = NULL
  Col1 has to be 1, Col2 or col3 can be any value
- Var1= 0, Var 2 = NULL, Var3 = NULL
  Col1 has to be 0, Col2 or col3 can be any value
- Var1= 1, Var 2 = 1, Var3 = NULL
  Results with (0,0, ANY) is not allowed. (1,1,ANY) (1,0,ANY) (0,1,ANY) are allowed
- **Var1= 1, Var 2 = 1, Var3 = 1

  Result with (0,0,0) is not allowed. Possible Results (1/0,1/0, 1/0), (1,1,1)**
- Var1= 0, Var 2 = 1, Var3 = 1
  Col 1 has to be 0, Possible Results (0,1/0,1/0), Not allowed: (0,0,0)
- Var1= 0, Var 2 = 0, Var3 = 1
  Col 1 has to be 0, Col2 has to be 0, Col3 hast to be 1. Possible results (0,0,1)
- **Var1= 0, Var 2 = 0, Var3 = 0

  Col 1 has to be 0, Col2 has to be 0, Col3 hast to be 0. Possible results (0,0,0)**

I highlighted the difficult part. There is a difference in behaviour between the values 0 and 1. I cannot alter that logic, though. It has to work that way.

---

I have 3 variables: `@var1, @var2, @var3` corresponding to 3 columns `@col1, @col2, @col3`. Each column has a value of either 1 or 0, each var can have a vlaue of 0,1 or NULL. My statement looks something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl a
    ((a.col1 = @var1) OR @var1 IS NULL) AND
    ((a.col2 = @var2) OR @var2 IS NULL) AND
    ((a.col3 = @var3) OR @var3 IS NULL)
```

Comment: Can you try to describe using more *words* what you mean by "add up"

Comment: Your logic seems flawed. In your first example, you expect every row with `col1 = 1` when `@var1 = 1`. But in your second example, you expect every row with `col1 = 0 OR col1 = 1` when `@var1 = 1`. It is very difficult to reason about this without additional information about your desired logic. You should explain more thoroughly what you actually want. Perhaps it might be useful to supply a table with all 27 combinations of `@var1`, `@var2`, `@var3`, and the expected results of each combination.

Comment: Is described it in my post. Filtering for Col1 =1 and Col2 =1 should result in table 1

Comment: But what should happen when `@var1 = NULL` and `@var2 = 1` and `@var3 = 1`? Or when all variables are 1? Or when one or more of the variables are 0? Right now I cannot see any (simple) shared logic in the two scenarios you provided. So it would be very difficult (or even impossible) for me to provide tips for a working solution that is also expected to work for all other possible combinations of `@var1`, `@var2` and `@var3`. Sorry...

Comment: Setting a var to NULL means the corresponding colum can have any value. Setting one var to 1 means it the corresponding column can only be 1, the other columns can be any value. Setting 2 vars to 1 means: either col can have a value of 1 or 0, but both columns cannot be 0 at the same time, column 3 can have any value. Setting al 3 vars to 1 means that any col can be either 1 or 0, but not all 3 columns can be 0 at the same time.

Comment: I think criteria no. 4 & 5 are contradictory, they don't make sense when put together

Comment: Just re-read the updated criteria in the question. Criterium 4 says: "Not all 3 columns can be 0 at the same time if all 3 vars are 1. And not all 3 columns can be 1 at the same time if all 3 vars are 0." Now it becomes messy: the logic gets inverted as well when 0 is supplied instead of 1 in the variables? So when `@var1 = 1`, `@var2 = 0` and `@var3 = 0`, you want all rows where `col1 = 1 AND NOT (col2 = 0 AND col3 = 0)`?

Comment: Giving any var a value of 0 means that the corresponding columns values can be 0 only. I will clarify this more in another edit. Sorry

Comment: This screams of an XY Problem where you are asking for help on a solution you have already selected, rather than help defining the best solution to your problem.  Can you please add some raw data, your table structure and desired outputs?  This can almost certainly be achieved in a much simpler way than the answers so far, but to find that solution, we need to know the actual problem.

Comment: Ok. I will formulate the problem I'm trying to solve in another edit. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @iamdave,I've edited my post with an explanation of the problem and the desired outcome/solution

Comment: @ChrisS I think I have a workable solution, provided below

Answer (score 0):

Simply ADD the values of the *n* columsn and verify if the addition is >= 1

Comment: That would show results if any column has a value of 1. But that is not what it should do.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your use case, I think this does what you need it to.  There is some explanation in the comments but I think the conditional logic should be pretty self explanatory.  I am not sure how well this would perform on a larger dataset, though I would doubt an efficient solution exists without data model changes:

### Query

```
declare @t table(Item varchar(1),InHouseManufacturing int, Purchasing int, Outsourcing int);
insert into @t values
 ('A',0,0,0)
,('B',0,0,1)
,('C',0,1,0)
,('D',0,1,1)
,('E',1,0,0)
,('F',1,0,1)
,('G',1,1,0)
,('H',1,1,1)
;

declare @InHouseManufacturing int = 1
       ,@Purchasing int
       ,@Outsourcing int = 0
;

select *
from @t as t
where case when @InHouseManufacturing is null   -- No selection = Return all
            and @Purchasing is null
            and @Outsourcing is null
           then 1
           else case when @InHouseManufacturing = 0   -- All filters = Handle in subsequent criteria
                      and @Purchasing = 0
                      and @Outsourcing = 0
                     then 1
                     else case when case when isnull(@InHouseManufacturing,1) = 1 then t.InHouseManufacturing else 0 end    -- Add up any matching criteria
                                  + case when isnull(@Purchasing,1) = 1 then t.Purchasing else 0 end
                                  + case when isnull(@Outsourcing,1) = 1 then t.Outsourcing else 0 end
                     
                                  > (isnull(@InHouseManufacturing,0) + isnull(@Purchasing,0) + isnull(@Outsourcing,0))     -- Where there are any matches
                               then 1     -- Mark as having at least one of the required criteria
                               else 0
                               end
                     end
            end = 1
  -- And then exclude any where the specific criteria is explicitly filtered out
  and case when @InHouseManufacturing = 0
           then case when t.InHouseManufacturing = 0
                     then 1
                     else 0
                     end
           else 1
           end = 1
  and case when @Purchasing = 0
           then case when t.Purchasing = 0
                     then 1
                     else 0
                     end
           else 1
           end = 1
  and case when @Outsourcing = 0
           then case when t.Outsourcing = 0 
                     then 1
                     else 0
                     end
           else 1
           end = 1
  ;
```

### Outputs

```
@InHouseManufacturing = null
@Purchasing           = null
@Outsourcing          = null
+------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
| Item | InHouseManufacturing | Purchasing | Outsourcing |
+------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
| A    |                    0 |          0 |           0 |
| B    |                    0 |          0 |           1 |
| C    |                    0 |          1 |           0 |
| D    |                    0 |          1 |           1 |
| E    |                    1 |          0 |           0 |
| F    |                    1 |          0 |           1 |
| G    |                    1 |          1 |           0 |
| H    |                    1 |          1 |           1 |
+------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
```

```
@InHouseManufacturing = 1
@Purchasing           = 1
@Outsourcing          = 1
+------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
| Item | InHouseManufacturing | Purchasing | Outsourcing |
+------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
| B    |                    0 |          0 |           1 |
| C    |                    0 |          1 |           0 |
| D    |                    0 |          1 |           1 |
| E    |                    1 |          0 |           0 |
| F    |                    1 |          0 |           1 |
| G    |                    1 |          1 |           0 |
| H    |                    1 |          1 |           1 |
+------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
```

```
@InHouseManufacturing = 1
@Purchasing           = 1
@Outsourcing          = 0
+------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
| Item | InHouseManufacturing | Purchasing | Outsourcing |
+------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
| C    |                    0 |          1 |           0 |
| E    |                    1 |          0 |           0 |
| G    |                    1 |          1 |           0 |
+------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
```

```
@InHouseManufacturing = 1
@Purchasing           = null
@Outsourcing          = 0
+------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
| Item | InHouseManufacturing | Purchasing | Outsourcing |
+------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
| E    |                    1 |          0 |           0 |
| G    |                    1 |          1 |           0 |
+------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
```

```
@InHouseManufacturing = 0
@Purchasing           = null
@Outsourcing          = 0
+------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
| Item | InHouseManufacturing | Purchasing | Outsourcing |
+------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
| C    |                    0 |          1 |           0 |
+------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
```

```
@InHouseManufacturing = 0
@Purchasing           = 0
@Outsourcing          = 0
+------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
| Item | InHouseManufacturing | Purchasing | Outsourcing |
+------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
| A    |                    0 |          0 |           0 |
+------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
```